# Declare stored procedure with recompile

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server. I am facing an issue in which my stored procedure becomes slow after every couple of days. It seems like a stored procedure caching issue.
I came to know that I can declare my stored procedure as "with recompile". Will it cause any performance issue?

Comment: **Yes - of course**; after all, with this option, the stored procedure will be "recompiled" **before every execution** - instead of re-using an already existing execution plan

Comment: As Marc_s says it will generate a new plan each time without caching it. On modern Servers the recompile time is minimal. The only minor drawback is you won't get see the plan in certain DMV queries.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s . As Mitch is saying, this recompilation time would be minimum. Will it be good if my stored procedure is being hit at every minute ?

Comment: Aside from being off-topic, your question lacks any element which would make it answerable. You haven't included the stored procedure, you said nothing about the concerned tables and their indexes, nor about the maintenance plans, nor about the server load, the performance pattern or the actual performance data.

Comment: Is there something stopping you from... trying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I came to know that i can declare my stored procedure as ReCompile. Will it cause any performance issue ?

CPU usage time for compiling a plan  will be in milliseconds,but if you have many type of these queries running,they will add up  to CPU Cost and will cause high cpu issues

There are many other options  to overcome [parameter sniffing.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33698/parameter-sniffing-vs-variables-vs-recompile-vs-optimize-for-unknown).you can force statement level recompilation(from SQLServer 2008) ,if you have narrowed down the issue to few statements..This will help in recompiling only few areas of query and not entire proc